# Compare names to range and writing mismatches to new column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of names (A2-A200). In the following columns (B2-B200, C2-C200) I have further lists of names. Some of these can be found in column A but others aren't.

I'd like to check all names in B to D to see if there's a match somewhere in A2-A200. If not, it should be written on the same row but in a new column (D). For example

```
Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D
Mike    Mike    Paul    Paul
Helen   Helen   Phillip 
Peter   Steve   Mike    Steve
Lucy    Peter   Lucy    
Phillip Helen   Karl    Karl
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Does this have to be a formula based solution or would you consider a VBA solution? Also, what happens in case where BOTH names in B and C are not in column A?

Comment: @Remnant I can use macros as I'm working directly with the spreadsheet. Good point about both names appearing though. Ideally, I'd like these to be comma separated in Col D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula for column D

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B6,$A$1:$A$200,0)),B6," ")&" "&IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C6,$A$1:$A$200,0)),C6," "))," ",",")
```

If necassary replace the range  `$A$1:$A$200` with the extent of your data, or yet better use a table